# how to change the subscript in an array of arrays

Tags: ios, swift

I want to change subscript coordinates in an Array of Arrays [[Int]] in order to be able to address each value in a way similar to a spreadsheet, so assigning values, formulas across cells, etc.

Currently to address each value I need to subscript like table[2][1] = 12 or similar. I would like to subscript like a spreadsheet table[a][2] = 12, so that I can adapt long and complicated formulas in bigger speadsheets to similar tables using the same system used in spreadsheets.

The question is: how to change the subscript system in an efficient way? I send a simplified example to ilustrate the point

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var table = [[0,  1,  2,  3],
             [1, 32, 44, 25],
             [2, 12, 66, 43],
             [3,  3,  4,  5]]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(table[2][1])  // 12
    table[1][1] = 100
    table[3][3] = table[1][1] * table[3][1] * 10
    print(table[3][3])

    printArray(table: table, j: 3)


}

// MARK: - Function

func printArray(table: [[Int]], j:Int) {
    for i in 0...j {
        print(table[i])
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is the most efficient way. What you are asking for is how to make it easily understandable for viewing so that you can compare it with a spreadsheet grid. I wouldn't recommend changing your code to suit viewing needs. Also, I'm curious to know where you would be using hardcoded subscripts.

Comment: I see your point but there are many, long and complicated excel formulas to be translated, with IFs and other formulas concatenated,  so I need to adapt them easily and without errors to my IOS, so a tool to change subscript would help a lot

Comment: For example of formula: =SI(Y($Y$17>1;AA9>0;$H$10<=Tablas!$C$9);"NORMAL";SI(Y($Y$17>1;AA9>0;$H$10>Tablas!$C$9;$H$10<=Tablas!$C$10);"SUPERADA";SI(Y($Y$17>1;AA9>0;$H$10>Tablas!$C$10);"ROTURA";"N/A")))

Comment: You can use dictionary with letter keys and array values instead of array of arrays.

Comment: Why not create a wrapper class/struct containing your array of arrays as the data source and with different functions that accepts cell coordinates in a format you want like (‘C’, 9) or (‘$C$9’) etc

Comment: Mojtaba I see your point, it works  [ String: [Int] ]

Answer (score 2):

The closest solution I found is to use enums, like here:

```
enum Column:Int {
    case a
    case b
    case c 
    // and so on
}

extension Array {
    subscript(col:Column) -> Element {
        get {
            return self[col.rawValue]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            self[col.rawValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}


var table = [[0,  1,  2,  3],
            [1, 32, 44, 25],
            [2, 12, 66, 43],
            [3,  3,  4,  5]]


table[.a][2] = 12
let val = table[.a][2]
print (val)
```

Nevertheless, there are two *little* drawbacks:

- you first have hard-code all the "column" letters you want to access to the `Column` enum.
- then, something like `table[5][.c]` and `table[.a][.b]` will also be allowed - so you could access the rows via letter, not only the columns

Comment: Andreas I see a major problem, your solution is table[row] [column], but I need table [column] [row] the same as in Excel

Comment: So, with the first subscript you want to access the "inner" array, and with the second the "outer"?

Comment: what i mean is: Table > I would paste it from Excel in the matrix var table of IOS, very convenient. So columns and rows as indicated in my example. Formulas > I need Table [column][row] like in excel so to copy the formulas with the same subscripts

Comment: =SI(Y($Y$17>1;AA9>0;$H$10<=Tablas!$C$9);"NORMAL";SI(Y($Y$17>1;AA9>0;$H$10>Tablas!$C$9;$H$10<=Tablas!$C$10);"SUPERADA";SI(Y($Y$17>1;AA9>0;$H$10>Tablas!$C$10);"ROTURA";"N/A")))